# Image is not inserting in db from excel in java spring boot?

Tags: java, excel, image, spring-boot

Hi Everyone I'm beginner in Java Spring Boot.I want to read the data from excel.Data contains **both text and image**.I have **read text from excel** and **insert into db** successfully.But I could not read the image and I have to insert the image into db.I have attached the error below Can anyone give me a solution? Any help would be appreciate.Thanks in advance....

Image :
[image]

[image]

```
    @RequestMapping("uploadQuestion")
    public String uploadQuestion(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam Long examId, Model model,
            HttpSession session) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        int flag = 0;
        String id = (String) session.getAttribute("userId");
        model.addAttribute("examList", onlineExamMasterRepository.findAll());
        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
        List<OnlineExamQuestionMaster> quetions = new ArrayList<OnlineExamQuestionMaster>();
        List<OnlineExamOptionMaster> options = new ArrayList<OnlineExamOptionMaster>();
        if (file.isEmpty()) {
            model.addAttribute("info", "Please select a file to upload");
            return "onlinexam/questionUpload :: section";
        }
        InputStream in = file.getInputStream();
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(in);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Row row;
        System.out.println(sheet.getLastRowNum());
        for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
            OnlineExamQuestionMaster qm = new OnlineExamQuestionMaster();
            OnlineExamQuestionMasterPK qmp = new OnlineExamQuestionMasterPK();
            OnlineExamOptionMasterPK omp[] = new OnlineExamOptionMasterPK[4];
            OnlineExamOptionMaster om[] = new OnlineExamOptionMaster[4];
            qmp.setExamId(examId);
            qm.setLogTimestamp(new Date());
            qm.setLogUserid(id);

            flag++;
            row = (Row) sheet.getRow(i);
            System.out.println(row.getCell(0).toString());
            if (row.getCell(0).toString().equals(null)) {
                model.addAttribute("info", "Some columns are null please check and try");
                return "onlinexam/questionUpload :: section";
            } else {

                qmp.setQuestionId(Long.parseLong(formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(0))));

                if (onlineExamQuestionMasterRepository.exists(qmp)) {
                    model.addAttribute("message", "Already QuestionId with " + formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(0))
                            + " Exist for ExamId " + examId);
                    return "onlinexam/questionUpload :: section";
                }
            }
            if (row.getCell(1).toString().equals("")) {
                model.addAttribute("info", "Some columns are null please check and try");
                return "onlinexam/questionUpload :: section";
            } else 
            {
                row = (Row) sheet.getRow(i);
                Iterator<Cell> iterator2 = row.cellIterator();
                /*XSSFWorkbook workbook2 = sheet.getWorkbook();
                List<XSSFPictureData> pictures = workbook2.getAllPictures();
                Iterator<XSSFPictureData> iterator = pictures.iterator();*/
                while(iterator2.hasNext())
                {
                    PictureData pictureData = (PictureData)iterator2.next();
                    String fileextension = pictureData.suggestFileExtension();
                    byte[] data = pictureData.getData();
                    if(fileextension.equals("jpeg"))
                    {
                        qm.setImage(data);;
                    }
                    else
                        qm.setQidDescription(row.getCell(1).toString().trim());
                }

            }
            if (row.getCell(2).toString().equals("")) {
                model.addAttribute("info", "Some columns are null please check and try");
                return "onlinexam/questionUpload :: section";
            } else {

                omp[0] = new OnlineExamOptionMasterPK();
                om[0] = new OnlineExamOptionMaster();
                omp[0].setQid(Long.parseLong(formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(0))));
                omp[0].setOptionId("A");
                omp[0].setExamId(examId);
                om[0].setLogTimestamp(new Date());
                om[0].setLogUserid(id);
                om[0].setOptionDesc(row.getCell(2).toString().trim());
                om[0].setId(omp[0]);
            }
            if (row.getCell(3).toString().equals("")) {
                model.addAttribute("info", "Some columns are null please check and try");
                return "onlinexam/questionUpload :: section";
            } else {
                omp[1] = new OnlineExamOptionMasterPK();
                om[1] = new OnlineExamOptionMaster();
                omp[1].setExamId(examId);
                omp[1].setQid(Long.parseLong(formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(0))));
                omp[1].setOptionId("B");
                om[0].setLogTimestamp(new Date());
                om[0].setLogUserid(id);
                om[1].setOptionDesc(row.getCell(3).toString().trim());
                om[1].setId(omp[1]);
            }
            if (row.getCell(4).toString().equals("")) {
                model.addAttribute("info", "Some columns are null please check and try");
                return "onlinexam/questionUpload :: section";
            } else {
                omp[2] = new OnlineExamOptionMasterPK();
                om[2] = new OnlineExamOptionMaster();
                omp[2].setExamId(examId);
                omp[2].setQid(Long.parseLong(formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(0))));
                omp[2].setOptionId("C");
                om[0].setLogTimestamp(new Date());
                om[0].setLogUserid(id);
                om[2].setOptionDesc(row.getCell(4).toString().trim());
                om[2].setId(omp[2]);
            }
            if (row.getCell(5).toString().equals("")) {
                model.addAttribute("info", "Some columns are null please check and try");
                return "onlinexam/questionUpload :: section";
            } else {
                omp[3] = new OnlineExamOptionMasterPK();
                om[3] = new OnlineExamOptionMaster();
                omp[3].setExamId(examId);
                omp[3].setQid(Long.parseLong(formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(0))));
                omp[3].setOptionId("D");
                om[0].setLogTimestamp(new Date());
                om[0].setLogUserid(id);
                om[3].setOptionDesc(row.getCell(5).toString().trim());
                om[3].setId(omp[3]);
            }
            if (row.getCell(6).toString().equals("")) {
                model.addAttribute("info", "Some columns are null please check and try");
                return "onlinexam/questionUpload :: section";
            } else {
                qm.setAnswer(row.getCell(6).toString().toUpperCase().trim());
            }
            if (row.getCell(7).toString().equals("")) {
                model.addAttribute("info", "Some columns are null please check and try");
                return "onlinexam/questionUpload :: section";
            } else {
                qm.setMarks(Long.parseLong(formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(7))));
            }
            qm.setId(qmp);
            quetions.add(qm);
            options.addAll(Arrays.asList(om));

        }

        for (OnlineExamQuestionMaster h : quetions) {
            onlineExamQuestionMasterRepository.save(h);

        }
        System.out.println(options.size());
        for (OnlineExamOptionMaster h : options) {
            System.out.println(h.toString());
            onlineExamOptionMasterRepository.save(h);
        }
        model.addAttribute("info", flag + "Questions Uploaded Sucessfully");
        return "onlinexam/questionUpload :: section";
    }
```

][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VERwM.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VERwM.png)

Comment: You do not have what you think you have. Open a debugger, set a breakpoint, and look at the object to see its characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

Pictures are not cell content in `Excel`. They hover in a separate drawing layer ([XSSFDrawing](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFDrawing.html) in case of `XSSF`) over the sheet and are anchored to cells.

So if the need is getting pictures according to the position they are anchored to, then we need to

1. get the drawing layer
2. loop over all shapes in that layer and if the shape is a picture, then
3. get the picture
4. get the anchor position of that picture

Following example is doing that and produces a `Map` which maps `XSSFPicture` to their positions. I have got the [XSSFPicture](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFPicture.html) because they provide much more information than the `XSSFPictureData` alone. And the `XSSFPictureData` can easily got form the `XSSFPicture`.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ExcelGetPicturesWithPosition {

 static Map<String, XSSFPicture> getPicturesWithPosition(XSSFSheet sheet) {
  Map<String, XSSFPicture> pictures = new HashMap<String, XSSFPicture>();
  XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.getDrawingPatriarch();
  for (XSSFShape shape : drawing.getShapes()) {
   if (shape instanceof XSSFPicture) {
    XSSFPicture picture = (XSSFPicture)shape;
    XSSFClientAnchor anchor = picture.getClientAnchor();
    String cellAddr = "R" + anchor.getRow1() + "C" + anchor.getCol1();
    pictures.put(cellAddr, picture);
   }
  }
  return pictures;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  XSSFWorkbook workbook = (XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelWithPictures.xlsx"));
  XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  Map<String, XSSFPicture> pictures = getPicturesWithPosition(sheet);

  System.out.println(pictures);

  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Once having that Map it is easy to get the pictures while iterating the sheet. For example if we are on `int row = 2; int column = 1;`:

```
XSSFPicture picture = pictures.get("R"+row+"C"+column);
```